# android widget id only for current widget

Tags: android, widget, appwidgetprovider

Can I get my current widgetId inside `onUpdate()` method of `AppWidgetProvider`?

I found many posts about sending `appWidgetId` in field of Intent, but I can't understand where I have to get it before sending.

I didn't find the methods for getting only current widget Id without configuration activities.

Answer (score 0):

try in onUpdate

```
    int a = appWidgetIds.length;
```

If this returns 1, then:

```
    int yourAppWidgetId = appWidgetIds[0];
```

should return your appWidgetId.

### EDIT

without seeing any code it´s difficult to give You the right answer, but I will give You an example. If you created your RemoteViews for your widgets, you have to create an intent for every RemoteView. At this intent, You could set an ID, for example:

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName(), 
                    layout.your_widget_layout);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                YourAppWidgetProvider.class);

    intent1.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,widgetIds);
        intent1.putExtra("ID", "one");
```

Then create a PendingIntent, which You can set to remoteViews:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_widget_button_id_in_xml,
                pendingIntent);
```

If user pressed the widget, you can get id inside onReceive() with

```
    String a = intent.getStringExtra("ID");
```

But this is only an incomplete example, there is a lot more to do. I think it is a good way, if you read this tutorial:

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesgeneralprogramming/315-app-widgets-tutorial

There is a good example with an updateService.

Comment: If I allready add one widget, and try to add another, my configuration activity launch and it generate intent. That Intent receive by all my widget and I can't determine what widget was configurated because intent, that was send by activity, contain app_widget_id, but i don't have information for widget id in each widget for comparison